# Disabling security warning caused by BaseIntermediateOutputPath?

Tags: visual-studio, security

Our team overrides BaseIntermediateOutputPath (and other related properties) in our Visual Studio projects in order to have build artifacts go outside the main tree.  However, this causes an annoying warning dialog to appear when you open a project for the first time in a new location (which happens on new machines, when you check out a branch to a new location, have to delete corrupted .suo/.user files, etc.).  Is there any way to disable the warning?

FYI, we are using Visual Studio 2008, and we have encountered this warning on Windows XP as well as Windows 7, so it is not UAC-related.